# MySQL select on indexed columns

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I'm new to MySQL and have a few questions that I haven't been able to find any information on. Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a database with 5 columns: id, c1, c2, c3, c4
id is PRIMARY KEY
each row is unique across c1, c2, c3, c4 (if there is terminology you guys use for this let me know that too :))

I need to be able to search for an existing row in the table so I thought to put an INDEX on c1 which will reduce the number of rows from maybe 10,000 (100,000 at most) to a couple. My questions are:

1. How many rows do you estimate before the performance benefit of an index becomes "worth it"? Ballpark/anecdotal answers are fine.
2. Do I need any special syntax to tell MySQL to use the INDEX? Right now I am doing a "SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1='blah' AND c2='blah' AND c3='blah' AND c4='blah'" and I'm not sure if the INDEX is helping the query at all.
3. Any other suggestions for better ways to query the table welcome, just keep in mind that I'm a newb!! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, a "[composite key](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Composite_key)" is a key using more than one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess an index being "worth it" depends on how fast you need the query to run. With only hundreds of records, it'll be "pretty" fast either way. But in any case, an index should be faster because you avoid having to read all (in some cases *any*) records on disk. Even a query that takes 0.02s without an index might execute in 0.0004s with one. Once you get into the thousands of rows, you'll definitely want an index. So, you may as well always use an index for any columns used in JOINs or WHERE clauses, no matter how many rows.

MySQL *should* use your index. You can check by running an `EXPLAIN` query. (Just add `EXPLAIN` in front of your query, like `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM...`.) It will show what index is being used, if any. Keep in mind that you have to use the columns in the order they're specified in the [composite index](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Composite_key). So if your index is `c1-c2-c3-c4`, you can't just use it for `c4` without using the other columns too.

So, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = 'foo' AND c4 = 'bar'` would use your index for `c1 = 'foo'`, but it couldn't use it for `c4 = 'bar'` because you aren't using `c2` or `c3`. Since you're using all four columns in the index, the index should be used for all of them. Make sense?

Comment: EXPLAIN is exactly what I needed to see what was going on. fyi, MySQL is using the index and I tested it out with a few different select statements to see how it behaved so I should be good to go! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @neurotic: Do you have an index on `c1` or an index on `(c1,c2,c3,c4)` ?

Comment: @ypercube Good question. I had originally understood there to be a unique index on `(c1,c2,c3,c4)` and wrote my answer thus, but after rereading the question I'm not entirely certain. I guess we'll find out.

Comment: @neurotik Oh. Do you have indexes for `c2`, `c3`, and `c4`? If not, why not? You always want to have columns used in `WHERE` conditions or `JOIN`s in an index. As explained in my answer, if your queries will always have conditions for `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, and `c4`, one combined index on `(c1,c2,c3,c4)` is a better choice than four separate ones.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking... The reason I have only c1 indexed is because 99% of the time it will be able to determine a unique row by itself, and even if it can't, it will narrow the choice down to 2 or 3 rows so I figured there was no need for the index to include c2, c3, c4 in this case. I can see why you would want to index all 4 columns most of the time though.

Comment: Now that I re-read what I just wrote I realize that there is a lot of redundant information being stored in this table so I maybe have to rethink the design, but at least my question is answered! :)